# How to filter select input using like clause in php

Tags: php

I am trying to filter the content based on location and category where category is fetched from dropdown 
but when filtering on basis of category it doesn't show the data row in which the particular option of dropdown is present
Here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['filter']))
{
$location = $_POST['location']; //input type = text
$category = $_POST['category']; //select type
$query = "
SELECT * FROM detail
WHERE  `c_JobCategory` LIKE '%".$category."%'
OR  `c_City` LIKE '%".$location."%'
OR `c_Country` LIKE '%".$location."%'

";
$search_result = filterData($query);
}
```

it is working when filtering on basis of location but not on category based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "
SELECT * FROM `detail`
WHERE  `c_JobCategory` LIKE '%$category%'
OR  (`c_City` LIKE '%$location%'
OR `c_Country` LIKE '%$location%')";
```

i hope it'll help

Comment: Now it is not taking location

Comment: you can use OR instead of AND if you want to filter if only one condition satisfies